# React - Redux Form - handleSubmit

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

Looking for some insight with the Redux Form handleSubmit function. I am following along to Set Griders course from Udemy. Everything is running smoothly until here. Other error/bugs I was able to research and solve them myself. I am really struggling to find a solution here.

**singin.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { Checkbox, Form, FormField, Button, Grid, GridColumn, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class SignIn extends Component {
onFormSubmitHandler({ email, password }) {
  console.log('Values', email, password)
}

render() {
  // this.props are brought to us by reduxForm. Allowing to grab the field inputs and submit action
  const { handleSubmit, fields: { email, password } } = this.props
  return (
    <Grid centered columns={2}>
      <GridColumn>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onFormSubmitHandler.bind(this))}>          
          <FormField>
            <label>Email:</label>
            <Input placeholder='Email' {...email} />
          </FormField>
          <FormField>
            <label>Password:</label>
            <Input placeholder='Password' {...password} />
          </FormField>
          <FormField>
            <Checkbox label='I agree to the Terms and Conditions' />
          </FormField>
          <Button action='submit'>Sign In</Button>
        </Form>
      </GridColumn>
    </Grid>
  )
}
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'signin',
  fields: ['email', 'password']
})(SignIn)
```

**rootReducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import SetsReducer from './SetsReducer'
import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  sets: SetsReducer,
  form
})

export default rootReducer
```

The console.log inside onFormSubmitHandler logs: 'Values undefined undefined'

Edit: [Project on GitHub](https://github.com/AdamSackfield/flashCards.git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The fix involved importing 'Field' from redux-form and replacing the input element with  elements. Passing {Input} as the component to render